# Android apk expansion file libs problems

Tags: android, apk

I'm following the steps in the dev guide to implement the Google Marketplace (Play) Expansion files setup:

http://developer.android.com/guide/market/expansion-files.html

I'm at the section "Preparing to use the Downloader Library" where I've added the License Lib, Downloader lib and zip lib projects to eclipse and then as libs to my main project. My question is about compatibility. My main project is set to minimum API 8 (Android 2.2), yet the Market Downloader Library (found here: android-sdk-mac_x86/extras/google/market_apk_expansion) is set to Android 4 and definitely uses methods from API 11. So how will this work?

The link says:

> Note: By default, the Downloader Library requires API level 4, but the
>   APK Expansion Zip Library requires API level 5.

Should I be looking for an older library?

Comment: I've thought about the idea of looking for older android-sdk installs (where the extras folder is older) but I can't seem to find where to get them.

Comment: The problem may be related to this issue which I've just replied to:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9612174/styles-xml-error-in-eclipse-library-project-for-google-downloader-when-app-is-pr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to fix the problem by removing a `values-v9` folder in `android-sdk/extras/google/market_apk_expansion/downloader_library` project.

Although this Library Project is built using Android 4.0, it seems to work fine in my Android 2.2 project as a reference library.

Comment: how did you get that working in 2.2?  The downloader library uses stuff that is only in api 11 and 13, from what I saw.

Comment: I think the key here is that the downloader lib is a reference Library added to your main project. I'm not expert on this, perhaps the lib adapts to use API 8 methods only, when detecting use in an API 8 project. Once I deleted the values-v9 folder in the Library project, cleaned / refreshed, my main project ran ok.

Comment: thx for the update.  yeah - I was able to run the app that referenced the libraries, but I haven't tried to use the downloader yet.  Did you actually make use of it?  There are some constants that are new in api 11/13, and at least one method.

Comment: Yes, the code seems to work fine and the expansion file is downloading ok once you have changed filesize to match your zip (new XAPKFile(true, 1, 245991L)). The problems I had was with the google servers deciding to send UNLICENSED responses on occasion. This whole process of using Expansion files was very painful and overly complicated. You wouldn't believe how much money has been wasted by myself and my team trying to work through this process. I added a bug to Google's dev guide page to ask them to remove / update the inconsistencies with the documentation.

Comment: thx - good to know things can work to some degree (you have issue# for the bug you filed?).  I've read of weirdness with lvl sending unlicensed responses.

Comment: The bug (26646) is a little unrelated to this particular issue, but is related to the apk expansion documentation; more specifically, the missing SampleZipfileProvider class.

Answer (score 1):

The APK Expansion File Library expects to be compiled against the most recent SDK versions, but supports a target SDK version of 4/5.