# styles.xml error in eclipse library project for google downloader when app is preApi9

Tags: android

I am playing with the new google expansion pack stuff, and the google library project for the downloader has a special values-v9/styles.xml file for the notification text properties.  This causes an error when the app that is using the library is preAPI9... at least for me.  It is referring to some style stuff that only appeared in api9.  I've tried setting

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8"  android:targetSdkVersion="9" />

in the AndroidManifest.xml of the main app, but this didn't help.  I would (naively) hope eclipse would just ignore the error if I'm building for api8, and then when deployed on the market the system would use the values-9 stuff if the phone were at or above that level, but it doesn't seem to work that way.  So, I'm hoping I'm missing something trivial here.

btw - here are the specific errors

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.StatusBar.EventContent.Title'.   styles.xml  /Google Play Downloader Library/res/values-v9   line 4  Android AAPT Problem

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.StatusBar.EventContent.Title'.   styles.xml  /Google Play Downloader Library/res/values-v9   line 4  Android AAPT Problem

Comment: Setting the target to 9 and the minSdkVersion to 8 in the manifest works fine for me, as long as I'm compiling against 9 as a target; did you also set the target on the project? (from the Android Properties panel)

Answer (score 5):

Yes, I'm getting this also. I posted a related question here:
[Android apk expansion file libs problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9607066/android-apk-expansion-file-libs-problems)

I'm stumped to know what to do.

Update:
This worked for me. I deleted the values-v9 folder and rebuilt everything. The DownloadManager is now working. How, I don't know.

Comment: I'm wondering if we are suppose to delete the values-v9 folder if we are to use it in our API 8 project - hence the reason for the v9 label. I'm guessing here.

Comment: hey elprl I think that it needs that folder so that it can color the text correctly on the newer versions of the os.  The trick is getting it to work in 8 in eclipse, imo.  I've seen some weird stuff before where you test in the higher api, and right before you deploy you switch the sdk back, but that makes me a bit nervous.

Comment: You might be right, if you are going to use it in newer API levels. However, you'll see the same style name/id in the standard 'values' folder, so wouldn't the newer versions just use those values anyway?

Answer (score 1):

Try changing build target via Project->Properties->Android AND/OR Clean your project via Project->clean...

This worked for me after having to manually create the styles.xml file inside the styles-v9 folder through windows explorer.

Answer (score 1):

I've fixed this error by building the project with the following commands:

```
android update project -p . -t 3 --target android-10
ant release
```

The first command tells to use the Android 2.3.3 toolchain for buiding the project.
Note that I still have android:minSdkVersion="8" in AndroidManifest.xml.

You should not delete the values-v9/ folder. Removing it can cause displaying notification with dark font on dark background.

Answer (score 0):

If you download the latest api version, you should be able to build the library project against that correctly.

At runtime, Android will discard any code that doesn't work with the api on the device (you'll see various log messages about this), and ignore any res folders with a too high version number. Watch out for the v11 notification code, however: it only works on v14 and above so you'll have to change the code which decides which notification to use.